# How to identify the document in MarkLogic having special characters

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

How to identify the documents having special characters in Marklogic. Documents are in UTF-8 format

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the use case? Are there things you are looking for to include punctuation, or are you trying to identify mangled docs that have mangled/junk characters when multi-byte characters were read as single-byte characters (such as curly-quotes and em-dash that was cp-1252 encoded but read as UTF-8)?

Comment: I am talking about mangled/junk characters @MadsHansen